# Inverse-closed subsets generating simple groups in finitely many steps

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

Let $G$ be an infinite simple group. Suppose there is a subset $X$ of $G$ with
$$
X^g = gXg^{-1}=X\qquad (g \in G)
$$
which is closed under taking inverses and which even generates $G$ in finitely many steps:
$$
X^m = G
$$
for a suitable $m \ge 2.$

We somehow suspect that $X$ might be equal to $G.$ *If so*, we have to establish (in the end!) that $X$ is actually closed under the multiplication; this would make $X$ a nonidentity normal subgroup of $G,$ and hence $X=G.$

But suppose this direct approach meets serious difficulties. What are then possible ***indirect*** approaches here? Anyone who met this situation in their own research, or elsewhere is kindly requested to share their ideas.

Comment: I don't believe this is true: what about, say, the set of three-cycles in an alternating group?

Comment: It is an example of X with all the properties above, but in your case X isn't equal to A_n. Conjugacy classes generate simple groups (and quite often even in finitely many steps), but I never said X is a conjugacy class.

Comment: Might be I must require G be infinite. The question, however, makes sense for finite groups, either. X is not defined in any exact terms.

Comment: If it helps: X need not be equal to G in either the finite or the infinite case.  In other words, your personal X must have some special feature not yet mentioned, so you may also be able to search for the missing hypothesis as a way to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, something like that. I have a condition \xi(v) that defines X. It might be proven that \xi(v) => \xi(v^{-1}) and that every element of G is a product of at most m elements with \xi. The problem is whether all elements of G satisfy \xi. I just wonder if anyone encountered the similar situation. I hope somebody did.

Comment: It would be enough to show that every conjugacy class contains at least one element that satisfies your condition (since X is a union of conjugacy classes). Of course, this may be no simpler than showing that every element of G is in X.

Comment: Right. That I tried.